# Does Ubuntu support multiple GPUs with multiple displays on each GPU?

Tags: display, gpu

I have zero experience with Ubuntu. But I would like to find out if what we want is possible. If so, I will be glad to start learning Ubuntu.

For our project we would like to have 3 GPUs in the system and connect 1 to 3 displays to each GPU. We will write our own game render software that will use Vulkan to render to all the displays.
Will that be possible? I did some search and it seems possible because more people are writing about it. But I do not understand the answers (about compositors and X11 config etc.).
All I want to know now is if this is possible, so that I have a very good reason to start learning Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes but this is too much related to hardware and not about Ubuntu.It is not Ubuntu or Linux does not stop you from using more displays...  Here is a link https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/18-gpus-in-a-single-rig-and-it-works/31571 to someone that set his system up with 18. Do read the comments: you will need to check the limits of your motherboard.